# json parsing error with createrawtransaction with bitcoin-cli in regtest

Tags: bitcoin-cli, regtest, windows, createrawtransaction

I have been trying to use getrawtransaction to work with raw transactions in regtest and I have not been able to get it to parse correctly.  the general format I am using is this.  I am running this on powershell on windows 10 if that matters

`.\bitcoin-cli -rpcport=18532 -rpcuser=alice -rpcpassword=supersecretpassword createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"7b2d65b85487a891a3e0a9c541975fa7e681e571ea18982da49402e594ca2af1","vout":0}]' '{"bcrt1q27y3n03u3s52z8nlq2nt9xqyxxvk5lwxjmjxnh":25,"bcrt1qmgj8qfvhqqc049facx94qyeh57xl0lu96hck2":24.95}'`

I have tried all kinds of variations on quote schemes and escaping, but the json always fails to parse with the error
`error: Error parsing JSON: [{txid:7b2d65b85487a891a3e0a9c541975fa7e681e571ea18982da49402e594ca2af1,vout:0}]`

any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using quotes and escaping like this should work on Windows:

```
createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"7b2d65b85487a891a3e0a9c541975fa7e681e571ea18982da49402e594ca2af1\",\"vout\":0}]" "{\"bcrt1q27y3n03u3s52z8nlq2nt9xqyxxvk5lwxjmjxnh\":25,\"bcrt1qmgj8qfvhqqc049facx94qyeh57xl0lu96hck2\":24.95}"
```

There are a few other problems with your command, you aren't using the `-regtest` parameter and the second output address is not valid, but those are unrelated to this error.